# After format exact double with decimal value not return

Tags: java

Decimal format issues:

```
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("###.#####");
Double d = new Double(122433423424.59696D);
System.out.println(format.format(d));
```

Output:

> 122433423424.59695

but need exact value like:

> 122433423424.59696

Comment: Do you want a `BigDecimal`? Doubles aren't precise enough.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: yes same issues BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal(122433423424.59696D);

Comment: Use a string in the `BigDecimal` constructor for exact precision, not a double literal.

Comment: i try double(11,5) length work fine but double(12,5) length  not work

Comment: It is impossible to store EXACT float (double) value in the memory of hardware.

Comment: but i need same value in output like 122433423424.59696

Comment: floating point has two main problems. 1. accuracy 2. representation. Widely described in internet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use string constructor of BigDecimal, ie

```
new BigDecimal("12243342342.59696")
```